# Can trigger enter be directional i.e trigger enter to happen only in one side and not on all sides of a collider in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, collision-detection, unityscript

In my game the player running in forward direction on a path triggers the collider to instantiate the enemies, when the same player comes in opposite direction and triggers the collider i dont want the player to instantiate enemies. How to achieve this please help..

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question, I see two possible situations here:

1. The player is only allowed to trigger when moving forward through it.
2. The player is only allowed to trigger when coming from a certain direction.

The first one would be quite easy. You can get the movement direction from the character controller to see if he's moving forward. You can for example try to use `Transform.LookAt` and compare it with the rotation of the player.

The second one is approached differently. For example, your trigger may only respond when the player moves forward along the x-axis. Then you record the X position as the very last thing in your movement loop. Then compare your X position in the next frame with the position in the last frame. If the difference between them is positive, you are moving in a positive direction. If negative, your moving in a negative direction.

Comment: Would you please consider retagging posts mistagged as 'Unity' as 'Unity3D'.  This is the 4th or 5th such post I've retagged that you answered and left unmodified.  If you want rep points, fine, but let the community engage after.

Comment: Ok I will, I've added the `Unity` tag and whenever I see the oppertunity, I'll retag it to `Unity3D`. Thank you for your help categorizing it correctly!